# how to Detect selected item in ContentControl in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I'm trying to develop a HamburgerMenu. a ContentControl  that i restyled it.
my xaml code is something like this :

```
 <Style TargetType="local:HamburgerMenu"> 
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:HamburgerMenu">                 
                <Grid x:Name="mainGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <!--HamburgerMenu button-->
                    <Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" Width="50">
                        <ToggleButton  x:Name="menuIcon" Background="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" Width="50" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:HamburgerMenu}}, Path=IsOpen}">
                            <Path x:Name="path"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Uniform" Width="30" Fill="{TemplateBinding MenuIconColor}" Data="M2,15.5L22,15.5 22,17.5 2,17.5 2,15.5z M2,10.5L22,10.5 22,12.5 2,12.5 2,10.5z M2,5.5L22,5.5 22,7.5 2,7.5 2,5.5z"/>                               
                        </ToggleButton>
                    </Border>
                    <!-- HamburgerMenu Items List-->
                    <ListBox x:Name="listbox" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,40,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" SelectedIndex="0"/>
                </Grid>                    
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>      
</Style>


 <Style TargetType="local:HamburgerMenuItem">    
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:HamburgerMenuItem">
                <Button x:Name="ListBoxItemButton" Command="{TemplateBinding SelectionCommand}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                            <Grid Background="Transparent" Margin="0" Width="300">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="45" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" Margin="10,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontSize="18" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                                    <Image Source="{TemplateBinding Icon}" Margin="10,5,5,5"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid Name="ItemSelectedIndicator"    Grid.Column="0" Background="{TemplateBinding SelectionIndicatorColor}" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                    </Grid>
                </Button>                
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and this is my HamburgerMenu classes :

```
 public class HamburgerMenu : ContentControl
{

    public new List<HamburgerMenuItem> Content
    {
        get { return (List<HamburgerMenuItem>)GetValue(ContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ContentProperty, value); }
    }

    public new static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Content", typeof(List<HamburgerMenuItem>), typeof(HamburgerMenu),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure));

    static HamburgerMenu()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(HamburgerMenu), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(HamburgerMenu)));
    }

    public override void BeginInit()
    {
        Content = new List<HamburgerMenuItem>();
        base.BeginInit();
    }

}

public class HamburgerMenuItem : ListBoxItem
{
    static HamburgerMenuItem()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(HamburgerMenuItem), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(HamburgerMenuItem)));
    }
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(HamburgerMenuItem), new PropertyMetadata(String.Empty));       

}
```

my question is how i can find witch ListBox item is selected in my window where i used my custom Control.

Comment: A ContentControl isnt the right control to inherit from. Have a look at ItemsControl or even ListBox that has selection build in. Restyle it or create a new ControlTemplate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a "SelectedItem" dependency property to your custom control and bind the `SelectedItem` property of the `ListBox` in the `ControlTemplate` to this one:

```
<!-- HamburgerMenu Items List-->
<ListBox x:Name="listbox" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,40,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" SelectedIndex="0"/>
```

You then bind your new dependency property to the source property in your window:

```
<local:HamburgerMenuItem ... SelectedItem="{Binding YourSourceProperty}" />
```